# Correlated subqueries MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, aggregate-functions

Apparently I don't understand how correlated subqueries
work under the hood.

I have the following 'Sales' table schema:
sale_id|sale_date|product_type

My goal is to calculate the ratio of sold products of certain type to the total number of products
sold on that date.

For example:

```
1. 2015-01-03 product_1
2. 2015-01-03 product_1
3. 2015-01-03 product_3
4. 2015-01-04 product_4
5. 2015-01-05 product_1
```

My output for product_1 should be:

```
2015-01-03 0.667
2015-01-04 0
2015-01-05 1
```

Here is my idea of code (we receive single sale_date one by one from outer query s1 and
perform select query with it inside inner queries). Obviously this didn't work:

```
select distinct s1.sale_date, count(select * from sales s2
                                    where s2.sale_date = s1.sale_date
                                    and s2.product_type = 'product1')/
                              count(select * from sales s3
                                    where s3.sale_date = s1.sale_date)
from sales s1
```

Please help me to crack this problem!

Comment: Presumably, '1'-'5' are primary key ids?

Comment: Correlated subquery is executed for each separate row, and row column of external table in correlated subquery text is replaced with the value for this row. So, for the row in which `sale_date='2015-01-03'` the correlated subquery will be executed as `select * from sales s2 where s2.sale_date = '2015-01-03' and s2.product_type = 'product1'`.

Answer (score 2):

The query you wanted to write has the counts *inside* the subqueries:

```
select distinct s1.sale_date
    (select count(*) from sales s2 where s2.sale_date = s1.sale_date and s2.product_type = 'product1')
    / (select count(*) from sales s2 where s2.sale_date = s1.sale_date) as ratio
from sales s1
```

However, this is really inefficient. What you ask for is much simpler done with conditional aggregation, like so:

```
select sale_date, avg(product_type = 'product1') as ratio
from sales
group by sale_date
```

This groups data by `sale_date`; `product_type = 'product1'` evaluates as `1` when the product type matches, else `0`. You can average that value over each group to get the daily ratio of that product.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll work on this!